# angular7 the type 'Observable <Object>' cannot be assigned to the type 'Observable <Grupo> []

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm getting this error when assigning an observable to the class:

*The type 'Observable ' cannot be assigned to the type 'Observable <Grupo []>'. Type 'Object' does not have the following properties of type 'Grupo []': length, pop, push, concat*

**Interface**

```
export interface Grupo {
    id?: number;
    exames:Exames[];
    anexos: Anexos[];
    nome: string;
    descr: string;
    data: string;
    receita: string;
    data_sis:string;
    ver: string;
    cod_app: number;
    cliente: number;    
}
```

**Service**

```
getGrupoExame():Observable<Grupo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Grupo[]>(this.apiRoot)
    .pipe(
      delay(1500)
      )
    }
```

**Component**

```
grupo$: Observable<Grupo[]>;

this.grupo$ = this.apiExames.getGrupoExames();
```

Comment: getGrupoExames versus getGrupoExame maybe?

Comment: There is no issue in the code that you have provided. Here is a working Stackblitz that has no compile errors and no code changes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjvwzk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It was really a lack of attention, I was using both methods and testing it wrong. Thanks ZZe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the @Mike One, it was just a lack of attention, because he had declared two methods with similar names. The observable works correctly.